# Does $\int_a^b \text{Im}(f(t))e^{int}dt=0$ implies $f=0$ on $[a,b]$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a complex valued function of a real variable for which
$$
\int_a^b \text{Im}(f(t))e^{int}dt=0 \text{, for all } n.
$$
Is $\text{Im}(f(t))$ identicaly zero on $[a,b]$?

I think the answer is yes, but I don't know why.

Comment: Certainly not. Consider $f$ any real-valued function. Perhaps you mean $\mathrm{Im}(f(t)e^{int})$ instead?

Comment: @AlexBecker Good eyes, I meant $\text{Im}(f(t))$ is identically zero. Thank you.

Comment: In that case we might as well assume $f$ is real-valued and replace $\mathrm{Im}(f(t))$ with $f(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about the $L_2[a,b]$ function space: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L2_space

Probably it is important that $a$ and $b$ are multiples of $\pi$.

The key is that the $\varphi_n:=t\mapsto e^{int}$ functions *generate* the $L_2$ space: form an *orthogonal base* in the sence that every $f\in L_2$ can be uniquely written in the (potentially infinite) sum:
$\sum_n \alpha_n\cdot\varphi_n$ for some $\alpha_n\in\mathbb C$.
Then, using the "scalar product" $\langle \varphi,\psi\rangle := \int_a^b \overline\varphi\cdot\psi$, we basically arrive that your $f$ is   **orthogonal**  to all base vector $\varphi_n$.